# Converting time-series values into a python list

Tags: python, list, time-series

I am retrieving time-series values using **odeint** function. It solves a system of differential equation.

```
measurement_times = np.arange(0, 12,.1)
init = [.1,.1,.1,.1,.1]

def tar(y, measurement_times):
    T, U, V,W,I = y
    dT = 0.9*I*10.24 - T*0.0012
    dU = V*T*0.0154 - U*1*0.81
    dV = W*0.1*0.12 + U*1*0.81 - V*1.64 - V*T*0.015
    dW= V*1.64 + 0.7*1*0.47 - W*0.1*0.12 - W*U*1591.5*1
    dI= T*0.0012 + 0.8*U*1410.79*1- 0.9*I*10.24 - I*1*1934.77*1   
    return  dT, dU, dV, dW, dI
targetmodel= sp.integrate.odeint(tar, init, measurement_times)
```

If I print the values of **dU** it gives me some values like mentioned below.

```
for g in targetmodel:
    print(str(g[1]));
--------------------------------
    0.1
    0.09223727996210558
    0.0850835704105759
    0.07849011448256649
```

What I want is to convert the values into a list and assign that list to the variable **data**. Currently, I am doing it manually by copying the values and assigning to the variable **data**

```
 Manual way
    data = [0.1,0.09223727996210558,0.0850835704105759,0.078490114482]
```

I would like to find a way to do it automatically without assigning the values to variable **data** manually. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make a list and append the values into that using `append()`

Comment: How can I append my values of g[1] to variable data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that helps you

```py
data = []
for g in targetmodel:
    data.append(g[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following code after `targetmodel`:

since the `tagetmodel` is of `ndarray` you can use basic numpy slicing to tell it to select all rows and column at index 1 .(Index start at `0`)

```py
print(targetmodel[:,1].tolist())
```